# Modifying yaml file using shell script

Tags: shell, yaml

I am trying to modify "grafana.yaml" file, which is mentioned below

```
datasources:
    datasources.yaml:
      apiVersion: 1
      datasources:
      - name: Prometheus
        type: prometheus
        url: http://thanos-query.default.svc.cluster.local:9090
        access: proxy
        isDefault: true
      - name: CloudWatch
        type: cloudwatch
        jsonData:
          authType: default
          assumeRoleArn: ROLEARN
          defaultRegion: AWSREGION
```

shell script "test.sh", I am using to modify  yaml file is

```
#!/bin/bash

role_Arn="arn:aws:iam::*:role/*"

aws_region = "ap-southeast-1"

sed -i -e 's, AWSREGION,'$aws_region',g' ./grafana.yaml
sed -i -e 's, ROLEARN,'$role_Arn',g' ./grafana.yaml

# perform  few other operations

#then revert tha changes in grafana.yaml file

key1="assumeRoleArn"
value1="ROLEARN"

key2="defaultRegion"
value2="AWSREGION"

sed -r "s/^(\s*${key1}\s*:\s*).*/\1${value1}/" -i ./grafana.yaml
sed -r "s/^(\s*${key2}\s*:\s*).*/\1${value2}/" -i ./grafana.yaml
```

but its failing in last two lines with error
"sed: -i: No such file or directory "

The main motive is to modify the yaml file, use it and the revert the changes for next execution.
The "grafana.yaml" and shell script "test.sh" both exist inside the same folder.

Any help greatly appreciated!

I tried using -i option with \x27\x27 as I am using mac, and read that sed works differently with mac.

"sed -r "s/^(\s*${key1}\s*:\s*).*/\1${value1}/" -i \x27\x27 ./grafana.yaml"

Comment: Better use python `yq` in command line

Comment: agree about `yq` but also learn to check your shell code at https://shellcheck.net . for macOS, you need `sed -i'' ...`  . Good luck.